# How to downgrade to an earlier version of Visual Studio Professional 2017?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I accidentally applied an update to Visual Studio, and right now have installed version 15.9. However, I'd like to downgrade to version 15.7. How can I do this?

I have already tried uninstalling and reinstalling, but perhaps my uninstall wasn't clean because immediately upon reinstall, the VS version jumped back to 15.9.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To install specific older updates of Visual C++ 2017, you need to use the right additional parameters. See [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/productinfo/installing-an-earlier-release-of-vs2017).

Note if you specifically just wanted to use an older version the compiler toolset (the C++ 15.7 compiler) you can do that with the VS 2017 (15.9) IDE installed. See [this blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/side-by-side-minor-version-msvc-toolsets-in-visual-studio-2017/).